# Assistance regarding Unity Hub

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a complete beginner trying to learn Unity!

I have a problem!!

I installed Unity Hub and also installed 2021.1.13f1 version of Unity.

But, I created a new project and when I tried to open it

It always shows the following error

> "FAILED TO RESOLVE PROJECT TEMPLATE : FAILED TO DECOMPRESS [C:\PROGRAM
> FILES\UNITY\HUB\EDITOR\2021.1.1f1\EDITOR\DATA\RESOURCES\PACKAGEMANAGER\PROJECTTEMPLATES\com.unity.template.3d-5.0.4.tgz]."

Can Anyone please guide me how to solve this problem?

Note : I am using a Windows 10 Laptop

Comment: It may have to do with the project path being too long or having spaces in it. https://forum.unity.com/threads/failed-to-resolve-project-template-failed-to-decompress.663214/

Comment: @RetiredNinja Fixed!!
Thank you so much for answering to my query..
Helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

The path is too long I guess .Select another project directory such as E:\unity.